# Tic Tac Toe If else clash

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement

I am creating an app 3X3 Tic tac toe where 3X3 are all buttons and on the click listener I am checking the possible combinations that whether either of 2 players had made their "O" or "X". But in my "if-else" portion it is not checking the condition but directly executing the "if and else" part even if the condition is wrong.
I hope my problem is understandable and debug able. Any help would be appreciable ...

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id=v.getId();


    if(id==ONEbtn.getId()){      // 1stnd button**********************************************************8

        String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get1.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
        ONEbtn.setText(turn);

        String get2=TWObtn.getText().toString();
        String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();

        String get4=FOURbtn.getText().toString();
        String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();

        String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();
        String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

              if(get1.equals(get2) && get1.equals(get3)) { // comparing 2nd and 3rd button text with 1st btn
                  //Log.d("Value of 2btn", get2);
                        callToast(name, turn);}
              else if (get1.equals(get4) && get1.equals(get7))    // comparing 4th and 7th btn with first btn
              {callToast(name, turn);}
              else if (get1.equals(get5) && get1.equals(get9)){
                  callToast(name, turn);}

        turn=switchingTurn(turn);
        Log.d(TAG, turn+ name);
        }

    }else if (id==TWObtn.getId()){              // 2nd button**********************************************************8

        String get2=TWObtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get2.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            TWObtn.setText(turn);

            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();

            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get8=EIGHTbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get1.equals(get2) && get3.equals(get2))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get5.equals(get2) && get8.equals(get2)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

        turn=switchingTurn(turn);
        Log.d(TAG, turn+ name);}

    }else if (id==THREEbtn.getId()){                 // 3rd button**********************************************************8

         String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get3.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            THREEbtn.setText(turn);

            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get2=TWObtn.getText().toString();

            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();

            String get6=SIXbtn.getText().toString();
            String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get1.equals(get3) && get2.equals(get3))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get5.equals(get3) && get7.equals(get3)){
                callToast(name, turn);}
            else if (get6.equals(get3) && get9.equals(get3)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}

    }else if (id==FOURbtn.getId()){                  // 4th button**********************************************************8

        String get4=FOURbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get4.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            FOURbtn.setText(turn);

            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();

            String get6=SIXbtn.getText().toString();
            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get1.equals(get4) && get7.equals(get4))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get5.equals(get4) && get6.equals(get4)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}
    }else if (id==FIVEbtn.getId()){                     // 5th button**********************************************************8

        String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get5.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            FIVEbtn.setText(turn);

            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

            String get2=TWObtn.getText().toString();
            String get8=EIGHTbtn.getText().toString();

            String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();

            String get4=FOURbtn.getText().toString();
            String get6=SIXbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get1.equals(get5) && get9.equals(get5))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get2.equals(get5) && get8.equals(get5)){
                callToast(name, turn);}
            else if (get3.equals(get5) && get7.equals(get5)){
                callToast(name, turn);}
            else if (get4.equals(get5) && get6.equals(get5)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}
    }else if (id==SIXbtn.getId()){                      // 6th button**********************************************************8

        String get6=SIXbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get6.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            SIXbtn.setText(turn);

            String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

            String get4=FOURbtn.getText().toString();
            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get3.equals(get6) && get9.equals(get6))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get4.equals(get6) && get5.equals(get6)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}

    }else if (id==SEVENbtn.getId()){                    // 7th button**********************************************************8

        String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get7.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            SEVENbtn.setText(turn);

            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get4=FOURbtn.getText().toString();

            String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();

            String get8=EIGHTbtn.getText().toString();
            String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get1.equals(get7) && get4.equals(get7))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get5.equals(get7) && get3.equals(get7)){
                callToast(name, turn);}
            else if (get8.equals(get7) && get9.equals(get7)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}
    }else if (id==EIGHTbtn.getId()){                    // 8th button**********************************************************8

        String get8=EIGHTbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get8.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            EIGHTbtn.setText(turn);

            String get2=TWObtn.getText().toString();
            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();

            String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();
            String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get2.equals(get8) && get5.equals(get8))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get7.equals(get8) && get9.equals(get8)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}
    }else if (id==NINEbtn.getId()){                     // 9th button**********************************************************8

        String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();
        if(!get9.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            NINEbtn.setText(turn);

            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();

            String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();
            String get6=SIXbtn.getText().toString();

            String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();
            String get8=EIGHTbtn.getText().toString();

            if (get1.equals(get9) && get5.equals(get9))
            {callToast(name,turn);}
            else if (get3.equals(get9) && get6.equals(get9)){
                callToast(name, turn);}
            else if (get7.equals(get9) && get8.equals(get9)){
                callToast(name, turn);}

            turn=switchingTurn(turn);
            Log.d(TAG, turn+ "   "+name);}
         }

}

public void callToast(String nm, String trn) {

    Toast.makeText(this,nm+ "  Wins with sign  :"+trn,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}


public String switchingTurn( String Sign ){
    if (Sign.equals("0")){
         name=PL_A;
         playerA.setText(TAG+" "+ name);
         playerB.setText("");
         Toast.makeText(this, name+"  turn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        turn="X";


    }else if (Sign.equals("X")){
        name=PL_B;
        playerB.setText(TAG+" "+ name);
        playerA.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this, name+"  turn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        turn="0";
    }
    return turn;
}
```

Comment: You need to debug your code yourself . Seems more like logical issue . It will be useful if you debug each step in your code to find out what exactly is going on .

Answer (score 0):

I was doing very stupid mistake... What all I was doing is fetching value and then setting the value and keep comparing the old fetched value...
here is small portion of debugged code...

```
 if(id==ONEbtn.getId()){      // 1stnd button**********************************************************8

        String g1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();  // corrected here!!!
        if(!g1.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not allowed here!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
        ONEbtn.setText(turn);
            String get1=ONEbtn.getText().toString();

        String get2=TWObtn.getText().toString();
        String get3=THREEbtn.getText().toString();

        String get4=FOURbtn.getText().toString();
        String get7=SEVENbtn.getText().toString();

        String get5=FIVEbtn.getText().toString();
        String get9=NINEbtn.getText().toString();

              if(get1.equals(get2) && get1.equals(get3)) { // comparing 2nd and 3rd button text with 1st btn
                 // Log.d("Value of 2btn","<<"+get1+"<<"+get3+"<<"+ get2+"<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                        callToast(name, turn);}
              else if (get1.equals(get4) && get1.equals(get7)) {   // comparing 4th and 7th btn with first btn

              callToast(name, turn);}
              else if (get1.equals(get5) && get1.equals(get9)){
                  callToast(name, turn);}

        turn=switchingTurn(turn);
        Log.d(TAG, turn+ name);
        }

    }
```